# vue passing props to sub component will generate html attributes to wrapper root

Tags: vue.js, higher-order-components

So I have this component `PageWrapper` that has a `title` props.

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <slot />
</div>
```

And I have a wrapper component that forwards most props to its child:

```
  <PageWrapper v-bind="[$attrs]">
    <slot name="default"/>
  </PageWrapper>
```

It works as expected, except that my page wrapper root has an extra `title` html attribute that I don't want to be there.

```
<div id="page-wrapper" title="My Title">
  <h1>My title</h1>
  <!-- rest of the page -->
</div>
```

I have the feeling there is a confusion between html attributes and vue properties when forwarding to sub-component.

I thought this had to do with the difference between `$props` and `$attrs` but apparently not as it doesn't work in any case.

Can someone clarify this for me? How can I avoid this html-attributes behavior?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

you do not want to bind the attributes to the PageWrapper Component.
Instead just bind the title property.

```
<PageWrapper :title="title">
    <slot name="default"/>
  </PageWrapper>
```

EDIT:
Might also try to bind the attributes without the square brackets `v-bind="$attrs"`

Comment: I did try the remove the `[]`, but it doesn't change anything. I could pass the `title` prop but I want all attributes to be forwarded to sub-component, so it doesn't fit my need. This is weird that `$attrs` get added to html root of sub-component, isn't it?